# Complicated C++ template code

Tags: c++, templates

I've been working on a wrapper for opencascade C++ to C#.
My C++ is a bit rusty since I mainly worked with C# for the last few years.

Now I'm encountering the following problem and have not been able to figure out how to correct it:

```
#include <type_traits>

//! Trait yielding true if class T1 is base of T2 but not the same
template <class T1, class T2, class Dummy = void>
struct is_base_but_not_same : std::is_base_of <T1, T2> {};

//! Explicit specialization of is_base_of trait to workaround the
//! requirement of type to be complete when T1 and T2 are the same.
template <class T1, class T2>
struct is_base_but_not_same <T1, T2, typename std::enable_if <std::is_same <T1, T2>::value>::type> : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
class handle
{
public:
    //! Down casting operator from handle to base type
    template <class T2>
    static typename std::enable_if<is_base_but_not_same<T2, T>::value, handle>::type
        DownCast(const handle<T2>& theObject)
    {
        return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(theObject.get())));
    }

    //! Down casting operator from pointer to base type
    template <class T2>
    static typename std::enable_if<is_base_but_not_same<T2, T>::value, handle>::type
        DownCast(const T2* thePtr)
    {
        return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(thePtr)));
    }
};

class Foo
{

};

typedef handle<Foo> Handle_Foo;

Handle_Foo DownCastFoo(Handle_Foo const &T) {
    return Handle_Foo::DownCast(T);
}
```

The compilor errors are the following:

```
Error   C2672   'handle<Foo>::DownCast': no matching overloaded function found  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2784   'std::enable_if<is_base_but_not_same<T2,T,void>::value,handle<T>>::type handle<T>::DownCast(const T2 *)': could not deduce template argument for 'const T2 *' from 'const Handle_Foo'
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'std::enable_if<is_base_but_not_same<T2,T,void>::value,handle<T>>::type handle<T>::DownCast(const handle<T2> &)'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi there, I think these code definitions are now complete, let me know if I missed smth.

Comment: The code you posted contains at least one typo (well I hope so).  Create your [mcve].  Then compile it.  Get exactly the error you want to get fixed.  If you get a different error, fix your mcve.  Do not transcribe by hand.  Copy the code (via copy-paste), format with spaces, copy the error (via copy-paste), format it with spaces.  Do not summarize the error, include all warnings and error lines.  Asking someone to figure out what is a typo and what is your real error is unacceptable, not nice, bad, and generally not good.  If your example is too long, make it more minimal.

Comment: 3rd time is the charm they say ;)

Comment: `return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(theObject.get())));` seems to imply that `handle` has a `const T* get() const` method, and a constructor that accept's `T*`.

Comment: `template <class T>
struct is_base_but_not_same <T, T> :: std::false_type {}` is a little simpler. (You can drop the `Dummy` type from the base template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the provided example.

First, the example implies a `T*` constructor and `get()` method for the `handle` class. Add these to the `handle` class :

```
explicit handle(T*);
const T* get() const;
```

Second, You are trying to down cast from `handle<Foo>` to `handle<Foo>` which is a senseless operation. `Foo` isn't even polymorphic. Your down cast method seems specifically designed to not provide this overload, thus the error you are getting. Define `Foo` to be polymorphic and add a derived class `Bar`.

```
struct Foo { virtual ~Foo() = default; };
struct Bar : public Foo {};
```

Finally, change `DownCastFoo` to try to downcast to `Bar` instead of `Foo`, and the error is resolved.

```
typedef handle<Foo> Handle_Foo;
typedef handle<Bar> Handle_Bar;

Handle_Bar DownCastFoo(Handle_Foo const &T) {
    return Handle_Bar::DownCast(T);
}
```

As a final note, those `const_cast` look awfully suspicious. Unfortunately, there isn't enough information in your example to provide better advice.

---

Full correct example

```
#include <type_traits>

//! Trait yielding true if class T1 is base of T2 but not the same
template <class T1, class T2, class Dummy = void>
struct is_base_but_not_same : std::is_base_of <T1, T2> {};

//! Explicit specialization of is_base_of trait to workaround the
//! requirement of type to be complete when T1 and T2 are the same.
template <class T1, class T2>
struct is_base_but_not_same <T1, T2, typename std::enable_if <std::is_same <T1, T2>::value>::type> : std::false_type {};

template <class T>
class handle
{
public:
    explicit handle(T*);
    const T* get() const;
public:
    //! Down casting operator from handle to base type
    template <class T2>
    static typename std::enable_if<is_base_but_not_same<T2, T>::value, handle>::type
        DownCast(const handle<T2>& theObject)
    {
        return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(theObject.get())));
    }

    //! Down casting operator from pointer to base type
    template <class T2>
    static typename std::enable_if<is_base_but_not_same<T2, T>::value, handle>::type
        DownCast(const T2* thePtr)
    {
        return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(thePtr)));
    }
};

struct Foo { virtual ~Foo() = default; };
struct Bar : public Foo {};

typedef handle<Foo> Handle_Foo;
typedef handle<Bar> Handle_Bar;

Handle_Bar DownCastFoo(Handle_Foo const &T) {
    return Handle_Bar::DownCast(T);
}
```

---

Edit: It looks like `enable_if` is only used to avoid illegal overloads. If you use `static_assert` instead you will get nicer compiler errors.

Example using `static_assert` :

```
template <class T>
class handle
{
public:
    explicit handle(T*);
    const T* get() const;
public:
    //! Down casting operator from handle to base type
    template <class T2>
    static handle DownCast(const handle<T2>& theObject)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, T2>::value == false,
            "Can't downcast from between identical types");
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T2, T>::value, 
            "Can only down cast from a derived type to a base type");
        return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(theObject.get())));
    }

    //! Down casting operator from pointer to base type
    template <class T2>
    static handle DownCast(const T2* thePtr)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, T2>::value == false,
            "Can't downcast from between identical types");
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T2, T>::value, 
            "Can only down cast from a derived type to a base type");
        return handle(dynamic_cast<T*>(const_cast<T2*>(thePtr)));
    }
};
```

Now, your original use case will produce the error message `"Can't downcast from between identical types"`.

```
struct Foo { virtual ~Foo() = default; };
struct Bar : public Foo {};

typedef handle<Foo> Handle_Foo;

Handle_Foo DownCastFoo(Handle_Foo const &T) {
    return Handle_Foo::DownCast(T);
}
```

Comment: Thank that makes more sense. You know it's not always easy to try and decifer code someone else has produced 6 years ago. In a language I don't even code. I try to be more precise in the future when posting problems. Really appreciate your answer! I gave you an upvote (seems it is not publically recorded, because new members need at least 15 upvotes before they can give any).